# Screen Saver Settings

Tags: windows-xp, screensaver

I'm using Windows XP, there's a policy by admin that forces the computer to lock itself after some amount of idle time.  Is there anyway around this?

Comment: Actually, I would say it's a good way to prevent silly jokes from people if you forget to lock yourself, but I understand it can be annoying to some.

Comment: Wondering if this question wouldn't find more answers on ServerFault, though. It's a user-side problem, but it's about something done by a sysadmin.

Comment: I'm still having some trouble figuring out the difference, so if it does belong on ServerFault, let me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some applications that tend to prevent screen savers from engaging.
Examples,

1. The [JkDefrag](http://kessels.biz/JkDefrag/) tool (has a debatable screen saver concept of its own)

   - Video players like VLC, SMPlayer, Windows media player too do this

I am sure there will be a 'flag' to block the screen-idle-detect.

---

Check **Block APM & Screen Saver** at [dimin.net Utils page](http://www.dimin.net/software/utils.html)

> If your preferred program to watch TV, movies or whatever can't block APM or/and screen saver just run this tiny utility. It will stay in the system tray and block them all while running, close it and you have your screen saver and APM back again!

Link to [ZIP download](http://dimin.m6.net/software/utils/blockAPM_SCR.exe) -- Note: I have not tried this.

---

I hope you are ready to handle the potential misuse of your system when you are not around `:-)`

Comment: Block APM & Screen Saver does what it claims to do, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is a device that you plug into USB that moves the mouse every so often to prevent the computer from activating the screensaver.

[image: Mouse Jiggler]

[Constant mouse activity prevents sleep mode and screen savers (and their password prompts)](http://www.wiebetech.com/products/MouseJiggler.php)

[image: Phantom Keystroker]

[The Keystroker emulates a keyboard and mouse and periodically makes random mouse movements](http://www.thinkgeek.com/gadgets/electronic/ae83/)

Comment: Any link or name for such device ?

Comment: Links have been posted in my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can write a simple application that tells the system that it is always in use.  See the 
SetThreadExecutionState function documentation at:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373208(VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

There are ways to reset the security that will allow you to change the setting (as well as other settings) but the changes enforced by Group Policy will be re-applied as soon as you log on to the network.

Your ability to reset these options will also depend on your current level of accessibility on your local machine since it requires using functions or file access that is normally restricted.

The easiest way is to delete the registry.pol file found in the hidden location:
C:\Windows\System32\GroupPolicy\User\
and:
C:\Windows\system32\GroupPolicy\Machine\
This will effectively reset all your security back to defaults (which are typically full open access).

You can also use GPEdit (Start->Run->gpedit.msc)to reset specific security options (including full reset) but the same situation still applies where you likely won't have access to this tool and the changes you make will be reset back to company defaults the next time you log on the network.

I would recommend that if you need to change that setting, speaking with the security group on your requirements would be the best way to go. That setting is there to protect not only the company but also to protect you, and bypassing that security could be cause for firing or other recriminations.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, there is, but that safety is in place for a reason.  Imagine if your doctor didn't employ that policy, and anyone happening by a vacant workstation can have a peek into your medical file.

It also protects you.  What if someone at your workplace wanted to blame something on you?

Security protocols are there for a reason.

Comment: Yes, but he actually asks for an answer to his question, not for a morale. If you have a way to do this, propose it. If you just want to tell him that his question is not good, do it in comments.

Comment: I thought this was about answers to questions that anyone can find.  Many think security protocols are just a way for admins to make life miserable.  I thought the acceptable answer would be not to try to circumvent security protocols.

Answer (score 0):

Not if you can't mess with the registry, which I doubt you want to do on a network, if you even have access. However, see if you can find a program that will automatically move your mouse a tiny little bit even couple of minutes for you and put it on a flash drive. Then the computer would never be seen as idle.